# Which component should handle DB access in the Java EE stack with regards to the MVC pattern

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller, ejb, rdbms

I'm fairly new to both `Java EE` and `MVC`. I have to develope a web application using `Servlet`, `JSP`, `JB` and `EJB`. As most applications mine too needs to interact with a RDBMS.

A friend of mine sent me a wep App he developed in which he has a
*Serializable DbManager class*
in which a
*private transient Connection*
 exists as a member variable.

In all his servlets in which he needs DB access he has a DbManager variable. It is instantiate in the init method of the servlet and it is retrived like this :

```
this.manager = (DbManager)super.getServletContext().getAttribute("dbmanager");
```

All the queries are implemented as public methods of the DbManager Class.
I was wondering if this is a good way to implement such needs or if there is a better way to handle Db access and queries execution. I tought of implementing business logic and thus DB access as public methods in my EJBs.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Homemade `DbManager` style classes are redundant when you are living in a JavaEE environment. You can make use of [JPA](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro.htm) for performing all your database queries from a stateless session bean that forms the "controller" part of your MVC architecture:

```
@Stateless
public class OrderController {

     @PersistenceContext
     private EntityManager em;

     public void addNewOrder(Order order) {
         em.persist(order)
     }

     public List<Order> findAllOrders() {
         TypedQuery<Order> findAllOrdersQuery = em.createQuery("select o from Order o", Order.class);
         return findAllOrdersQuery.list();
         // In practice you would add pagination to this.
         // It's not practical to return a million orders to your view.
     }

     ...
}
```

This stateless EJB manages all transactions on your behalf, so you don't normally need to be concerned with beginning, committing and/or rolling back transactions.

The `Order` class is a component of your "model":

```
@Entity
public class Order {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String orderNumber;

    @Column
    private String description;

    // other attributes
    ...

    Order() { }

    public Order(String orderNumber, String description) {
        this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
        this.description = description;
    }

    // setters and getters
    ...

    // you must also override equals() and hashCode()

}
```

You will see many examples where developers introduce a so called [DAO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) layer into their controller, but this is considered redundant as the [EntityManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) essentially satisfies that contract.